# how to update a detached object in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a problem by updating a detached parent/child structure:
(one)order -> (many) orderLines

Here is what i'm trying to do:
*Open a session, load an order and then close the session.
*Make some changes at the order's lines.
*Make some changes at the order.
*Open a new session and no matter if i do:
      * session.save(order).
      * session.update(order).
      * session.merge(order).
The order's lines never gets updated.

Here is the code i wrote.

```
public class Order implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer idOrder;
    private String date;
    private List<OrderLine>;

    public Order(){}
    // getters and setters
}

public class OrderLine implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer idOrderLine;
    private Integer quantity;

    public OrderLine(){}
    // getters and setters  
}
```

In session one ------> load the order

In session two

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
order.setDate(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date()));

// the user has modified the quantity of each line and i want to update them.

// which method should i use: update() or merge() or ... ?;

tx.commit();
```

Here are my mappings:

```
<class name="Order" table="Order">
    <id name="idOrder" type="int" column="idOrder">
        <generator class="org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator"> 
            <param name="sequence_name">Order_SEQ</param>
            <param name="initial_value">1</param>
            <param name="increment_size">1</param> 
            <param name="value_column">CurrentValue</param> 
            <param name="optimizer">hilo</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="date"/>
    <list name="orderLine" table="orderLine">
        <key column="idOrder"/>
        <index column="idx"/>
        <one-to-many class="OrderLine"/>
    </list>
</class>

<class name="OrderLine" table="OrderLine">
    <id name="idOrderLine" type="int" column="idOrderLine">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property name="quantity"/>
    <many-to-one name="order" column="idOrder" not-null="true"/>
</class>
```

which is the best way to update the order and the order's lines?

Comment: doesn't look your object is detached, you wanna call update, you are still in your transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are closing the `session` using `session.close()` then you have to use `session.update()` instead of `session.merge()`. Also as there is no `cascade` property set in your mapping files, you have to save the `OrderLine's` before saving the corresponding `Order`.

Here is the sample code that works in your case:

```
private static void updateData(Order order) {
    Session session = getSession();
    session.getTransaction().begin();

    // To update existing OrderLines

    List<OrderLine> orderLines = new ArrayList<OrderLine>();
    for (OrderLine orderLine : order.getOrderLines()) {
        OrderLine ol = new OrderLine();
        ol.setIdOrderLine(orderLine.getIdOrderLine());
        ol.setOrder(orderLine.getOrder());
        ol.setQuantity(orderLine.getQuantity() + 10);
        orderLines.add(ol);
    }
    for (OrderLine orderLine : orderLines) {
        //session.merge(orderLine); -- merge() is used when we are not closing the session using session.close()
        session.update(orderLine);
    }

    // To create new OrderLine and updating existing Order
    OrderLine ol1 = new OrderLine();
    ol1.setOrder(order);
    ol1.setQuantity(80);
    order.setStartDate(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
            .format(new Date()));
    order.addOrderLine(ol1);

    session.save(ol1);
    //session.merge(order);
    session.update(order);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}
```